# Add block vigets one button

Tags: python, button, kivy, scrollview

I want in ScrollView window add block different vigets  one button, i did this block, but how i can add it and save it after exiting i don't know.

My application now is view so:

[image]

I want have button, which i can add this block like so:

[image]

And after press this button appeared this block AND after exting application all stay on their position

[image]

Code this application:

.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Screeen(Screen):
    def texxxt(self):
        with open("settings.txt", 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.ids.Write_here.text)

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Ball(App):
    def on_start(self):
        with open("settings.txt", "r") as f:
            content1 = f.readline()
            self.sm.get_screen("Screeen").ids.Write_here.text = content1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm: ScreenManager = Builder.load_file("plann.kv")

    def build(self):
        return self.sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Ball().run()
```

plann.kv:

```
Manager:
    Screeen:

<Screeen>:
    name: "Screeen"
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

            FloatLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: 1
                height: 250

                FloatLayout:
                    size: self.size

                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 190/255, 210/255, 240/255, .45
                        RoundedRectangle:
                            radius: [16]
                            size: self.width * 96 / 100, self.height * 80 / 100
                            pos: self.width * 2 / 100, self.height * 17 / 1000


                FloatLayout:
                    size: self.size

                    Label:
                        id: lable
                        text: "Write_text"
                        font_size: root.height * 1 / 48
                        bold: True
                        center_x: self.width * 1 / 2
                        center_y: self.height * 730 / 1000

                    TextInput:
                        id: Write_here
                        size_hint: (.8, .2)
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": .5}
                        hide_text: "write here"

                    Button:
                        id: but1
                        size_hint: (.6, .2)
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": .25}
                        text: "Save"
                        on_press: root.texxxt()
```

settings.txt:

```
-
```

And in end after added this block how to save text from it in "settings.txt" and upload in app how i did it in first time?